# probability of combinations for numbers 1-7

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics

In Japan, there is a Chimpanzee named Ai who can evidently understand numbers better than many college students. The numbers 1 - 7 appear on a computer screen for Ai. Ai then touches the screen to select the numbers in the correct order. Each time Ai selects a number, it disappears from the screen of choices.

What is the probability of getting the entire sequence correct (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) if the chimp, Ai, is just guessing?

Comment: hint permutations.

Comment: How many sequences are possible to have guessed?  We are told Ai is just guessing... does this imply that each of the possible sequences are equally likely to have been guessed?  How many of the sequences are actually correct?  What does the ratio of the number of these two amounts represent?

Answer (score 5):

So we know that we are trying to order 7 numbers (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) in this particular order. So the first thing we need to know is how many ways can we arrange these numbers. In order to find this out we can use a permutation. $P(7,7) =\frac{7!}{(7-7)! }$ which in our case equals $7!$

Since there is only one correct arrangement of these numbers the probability of arranging them correctly is $\frac{1}{7!}$. In one try you would have $\frac{1}{7!}$ chance of getting this correct assuming all numbers have an equal probability for selection.

Comment: it's not (7-7!) it's (7-7)!

Comment: Roddy you are absolutely correct. I edited the post. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

it is equal to 1/(7!)^x where x is equal to the number of times ai guesses correct. With one guess this equals 0.00019841269%

Comment: How did you get this number?

Comment: I recommend avoiding phrases like "this equals [number]" when the number that follows is an *approximation* and in particular is *not equal*.  Your inclusion of the `^x` is unnecessary and might just confuse the OP further and should not have been included.  Your post does give the correct answer, but gives no reasoning as to *why* that is the correct answer.  The *why* is generally agreed to be the most important and necessary part of a proper answer to the question here.  Try including in your answer the following: the significance of the number $7!$ and the reason to use a ratio